# Unpack Array of args to the stack and call function with those args using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection, reflection.emit

I am working on a c# project that uses Reflection.Emit.
I have the args on the stack for a function call to `Dictionary.ByKeysValues(IList<string>,IList<object>)`, but must first transform them with another function `Utils.UnmarshalFunctionArgs2` - this function returns an array of the transformed args.

My idea was to emit a loop over the array, where each arg would be pushed back to the stack, and then emit the final call to the original function.

I get the dreaded `CLR detected an invalid program exception`.

The c# view in ILSPY shows this:
(note the 3 errors)

```
static void Execute(IDictionary<string, IList> P_0, IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<FEP>> P_1, IDictionary<string, object> P_2, Runtime P_3)
{
    //IL_00b7: Incompatible stack heights: 0 vs 1
    P_1.TryGetValue(CodeGenIL.Hash("Dictionary", "ByKeysValues", 2), out var value);
    IList<object>[] array = Utils.UnMarshalFunctionArguments2(value, new object[2]
    {
        new string[2] { "key1", "key2" },
        new string[2] { "val", "val2" }
    }, P_3);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        _ = array[i];
    }
    Dictionary value2 = Dictionary.ByKeysValues((IList<string>)/*Error near IL_00cf: Stack underflow*/, (IList<object>)/*Error near IL_00cf: Stack underflow*/);
    P_2.Add("a", value2);
}
```

the IL

```
    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: ldstr "Dictionary"
    IL_0006: ldstr "ByKeysValues"
    IL_000b: ldc.i4 2
    IL_0010: call int32 [EmitMSIL]EmitMSIL.CodeGenIL::Hash(string, string, int32)
    IL_0015: ldloca.s 0
    IL_0017: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<int32, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [Assem]FEP>>::TryGetValue(!0, !1&)
    IL_001c: pop
    IL_001d: ldloc 0
    IL_0021: nop
    IL_0022: nop
    IL_0023: ldc.i4 2
    IL_0028: newarr [mscorlib]System.Object
    IL_002d: dup
    IL_002e: ldc.i4 0
    IL_0033: ldc.i4 2
    IL_0038: newarr [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_003d: dup
    IL_003e: ldc.i4 0
    IL_0043: ldstr "key1"
    IL_0048: stelem.ref
    IL_0049: dup
    IL_004a: ldc.i4 1
    IL_004f: ldstr "key2"
    IL_0054: stelem.ref
    IL_0055: stelem.ref
    IL_0056: dup
    IL_0057: ldc.i4 1
    IL_005c: ldc.i4 2
    IL_0061: newarr [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_0066: dup
    IL_0067: ldc.i4 0
    IL_006c: ldstr "val"
    IL_0071: stelem.ref
    IL_0072: dup
    IL_0073: ldc.i4 1
    IL_0078: ldstr "val2"
    IL_007d: stelem.ref
    IL_007e: stelem.ref
    IL_007f: ldarg.3
    IL_0080: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<object>[] [EmitMSIL]EmitMSIL.Utils::UnMarshalFunctionArguments2(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [Assem]FEP>, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IList, class [Assem]Runtime)
    IL_0085: stloc 1
    IL_0089: nop
    IL_008a: nop
    IL_008b: ldc.i4 0
    IL_0090: stloc 2
    IL_0094: nop
    IL_0095: nop
    IL_0096: br.s IL_00b8
    // loop start (head: IL_00b8)
        IL_0098: nop
        IL_0099: ldloc 1
        IL_009d: nop
        IL_009e: nop
        IL_009f: ldloc 2
        IL_00a3: nop
        IL_00a4: nop
        IL_00a5: ldelem.ref
        IL_00a6: ldloc 2
        IL_00aa: nop
        IL_00ab: nop
        IL_00ac: ldc.i4 1
        IL_00b1: add
        IL_00b2: stloc 2
        IL_00b6: nop
        IL_00b7: nop

        IL_00b8: ldloc 2
        IL_00bc: nop
        IL_00bd: nop
        IL_00be: ldloc 1
        IL_00c2: nop
        IL_00c3: nop
        IL_00c4: ldlen
        IL_00c5: conv.i4
        IL_00c6: clt
        IL_00c8: brtrue.s IL_0098
    // end loop

    IL_00ca: call class [Assem2]Dictionary [Assem2]Dictionary::ByKeysValues(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<string>, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<object>)
    IL_00cf: stloc 3
    IL_00d3: nop
    IL_00d4: nop
    IL_00d5: ldarg.2
    IL_00d6: ldstr "a"
    IL_00db: ldloc 3
    IL_00df: nop
    IL_00e0: nop
    IL_00e1: callvirt instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>::Add(!0, !1)
    IL_00e6: ret
} // end of method ExecuteIL::Execute
```

I understand the stack underflow errors to mean that there are not enough instructions that push values to the stack relative to the number of args the `ByKeysValues`will consume, but how is this determined given that the loop may put values on the stack?

In general, is there an appropriate way to call a function given an array of args when using IL?

Comment: How about unrolling the loop? As far as I know, loops in IL cannot do what you are trying to do - "each arg would be pushed back to the stack". The maximum stack size must be known at compile time.

Comment: @Sweeper - thanks! That worked great in my case as I will always know how many args there are.